# Channel Field sort order in EE3

Tags: control-panel, ee3

In EE2 there was a mechanism whereby the user/admin could move the channel fields about on a channel entry edit page and change their width to wrap short ones next to each other etc
This allowed the page to be much more compact and let the field creator create fields in any arbitrary order as they could be reordered later.

Is this still available in EE3? At present it appears as though the fields are displayed in 'natural' order and no reordering is present which results in some *very* long channel entry pages

Answer (score 5):

This feature has moved to the "Layouts" section of the Channel Manager. ([See docs.](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/channel/layouts/index.html))

[image: Channel Manager screenshot]

Comment: This is great - I see that the admin can move fields up or down in the order but not show more than one on a 'row' - a pity as some of our channels have 100+ fields and many are short fields for numerical displays which are much clearer when displayed together. This feels a little bit of a step back to me :(

Comment: Yeah, this is no doubt a result of the responsive control panel - a sacrifice which is worth it IMHO.

Comment: I just did a bit more testing with the field_order, and it appears that the {custom_field} loop DOES respect the field order. I still think Ellislabs should add support for the form layouts in exp:channel:form tag. /// I am at my wits end trying to figure out how to reorder the fields in the {custom_fields} loop. 1. I would have expected a way to reference a form layout when using {exp:channel:form} in a template. I see no documentation to indicate this! 2. I would have expected that the show_field parameter would al